# Get specific alert from Azure Monitor using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I want to get a specific alert from Azure Monitor using python (through an Azure function).
The Azure Monitor will triggered the az function for each Event.

Currently I'm using [get_all](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-mgmt-alertsmanagement/0.2.0rc2/azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement.operations.html#azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement.operations.AlertsOperations.get_all) from azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement.operations module, this allows me to get all alerts.
Also already tested get_by_id but I was obliged to specify the alert_id while I'm looking to get it automatically.

```py
import logging
import urllib3
import os
import json
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement import AlertsManagementClient


subscription_id =""
client_id =""
client_secret =""
tenant_id = ""

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
      tenant_id=tenant_id, 
      client_id=client_id, 
      client_secret=client_secret
)

print("===Auth Azure Monitor===")
client = AlertsManagementClient(
    credential,
    subscription_id
)

print("=== Get alert event from Az Monitor & Post it to monitoring platform === ")
headers = {'Authorization': f'authtoken {token}'}

for alert in client.alerts.get_all():
    if alert.name == "alert_rule_name" :
        attributes = {'CLASS': 'EVENT',
                      'severity': 'CRITICAL',
                      'msg': alert.name,
                      'lastModifiedDateTime': json.dumps(alert.properties.essentials.last_modified_date_time, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
                      }
        payload = [{'eventSourceHostName': alert.properties.essentials.target_resource_name, 'attributes': attributes}]
        print("JSON_PAYLOAD :", payload)
## Some code here to push the Alert to a monitoring platform ..
```

Please, find below the json sent by Azure Monitor with get_all :

```json
{'value': [{'properties': {'essentials': {
'severity': 'Sev2', 
'signalType': 'Metric', 
'alertState': 'New', 
'monitorCondition': 'Fired', 
'monitorService': 'Platform', 
'targetResource': '/subscriptions/sub_id/resourcegroups/rsg_name/providers/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/vm_name', 
'targetResourceName': 'vm_name', 
'targetResourceGroup': 'rsg_name', 
'targetResourceType': 'virtualmachines', 
'sourceCreatedId': '5f33r_rsg_name_microsoft.insights_metricAlerts_alert_rule_name-1899618006', 
'alertRule': '/subscriptions/sub_id/resourceGroups/rsg_name/providers/microsoft.insights/metricAlerts/alert_rule_name', 
'startDateTime': '2023-05-09T13:32:28.1880147Z', 
'lastModifiedDateTime': '2023-05-09T13:32:28.1880147Z', 
'lastModifiedUserName': 'System', 
'actionStatus': {'isSuppressed': False}, 'description': ''}
}, 
'id': '/subscriptions/sub_id/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/2222-5555-88888', 
'type': 'Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts', 
'name': 'alert_rule_name'},
```

As you see, I'm filtering by [if alert.name == "alert_rule_name"] and this is not what I'm looking for (I got a list of Events).

Is there a way to get the alert ID from the payload when Azure Monitor call my function ?
This is to use this ID to get a specific alert (event).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I added the python code with the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Monitor trigger the below Azure Function which parse only one Event and forward it to another destination in order to notify the support team :

```
import azure.functions as func
import os
import json
import requests
import urllib3
import logging

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("===== Auth Monitoring Platform =====")
    urllib3.disable_warnings()
    creds = {'username': "user", 'password': "****", 'tenantName': '*'}
    logging.debug(f'Retrieving authorization token')
    resp = requests.post(f'https://{api_url}', json=creds, verify=False)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
            logging.error(f'{resp.headers}')
            logging.error(f'{resp.text}')
            exit(1)
            
    token = resp.json()["response"]["authToken"]

    logging.info("===== Get Alert JSON & Prepare Post to Monitor Platform =====")

    req_body = req.get_json()
    
    msg_detail = {'firedDateTime' : req_body['data']['essentials']['firedDateTime'], 
                   'operator':       req_body['data']['alertContext']['condition']['allOf'][0]['operator'],
                   'threshold':      req_body['data']['alertContext']['condition']['allOf'][0]['threshold'],
                   'metricValue':    req_body['data']['alertContext']['condition']['allOf'][0]['metricValue']
                   }
    headers = {'Authorization': f'authtoken {token}'}
    attributes = {  'CLASS':           'EVENT',
                    'severity':        'CRITICAL',
                    'msg':             req_body['data']['essentials']['alertRule'],
                    'msg_detail':     mc_long_msg,
                    'object':       req_body['data']['essentials']['configurationItems'][0],
                    'object_class': req_body['data']['alertContext']['condition']['allOf'][0]['metricNamespace'],
                    'mc_parameter':    req_body['data']['alertContext']['condition']['allOf'][0]['metricName']
                 }
    
    payload = [{'eventSource': req_body['data']['essentials']['configurationItems'][0], 'attributes': attributes}]
    params = {'param1':"value1" , 'param2':"value2"}
    logging.info(f'Event header: {headers}')
    logging.info(f'Event payload: {payload}')     
    
    response = requests.post(f'https://{api_url}',
                       headers=headers,
                       params=params,
                       json=payload,
                       verify=False
                )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        logging.error(f'{response.headers}')
        logging.error(f'{response.text}')
        exit(1)
    
    logging.debug(f'{response.headers}')
    logging.debug(f'{response.text}')
    logging.info(f'Payload: {payload}')
    
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
        status_code=200
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the alert ID from the payload when Azure Monitor

You can use the below code to get an Alert id with payload using python.

You need to add **`alert.id`** in your attributes to get the alert id of your specific alert.

**Code:**

```
import os
import json
import requests
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.alertsmanagement import AlertsManagementClient


subscription_id ="your subscription id"
client_id =""
client_secret =""
tenant_id = ""

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
      tenant_id=tenant_id, 
      client_id=client_id, 
      client_secret=client_secret
)


print("===Auth Azure Monitor===")
client = AlertsManagementClient(
    credential,
    subscription_id
)
print("=== Get alert event from Az Monitor & Post it to monitoring platform === ")

for alert in client.alerts.get_all():
    if alert.name == "Backup Failure" :
        attributes = {'CLASS': 'EVENT',
                      'severity': 'CRITICAL',
                      'msg': alert.name,
                      'id': alert.id,
                      'lastModifiedDateTime': json.dumps(alert.properties.essentials.last_modified_date_time, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
                      }
        
        payload = [{'eventSourceHostName': alert.properties.essentials.target_resource_name,'attributes': attributes}]
        print("JSON_PAYLOAD :", payload)
```

**Output:**

```
===Auth Azure Monitor===
=== Get alert event from Az Monitor & Post it to monitoring platform ===
JSON_PAYLOAD : [{'eventSourceHostName': 'mm-automation-runas-account-2', 'attributes': {'CLASS': 'EVENT', 'severity': 'CRITICAL', 'msg': 'aa-test-1', 'id': '/subscriptions/bxxxxf/resourcegroups/management_migration-resources/providers/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/mm-automation-runas-account-2/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/3f481155-b808-a188-6exxxxxx', 'lastModifiedDateTime': '"2023-06-14 05:35:14.747028+00:00"'}}]
JSON_PAYLOAD : [{'eventSourceHostName': 'mm-automation-runas-account-2', 'attributes': {'CLASS': 'EVENT', 'severity': 'CRITICAL', 'msg': 'aa-test-1', 'id': '/subscriptions/bxxxxxf/resourcegroups/management_migration-resources/providers/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/mm-automation-runas-account-2/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/8cba3e70-c957-4xxxxxxxx', 'lastModifiedDateTime': '"2023-06-13 12:35:13.840749+00:00"'}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I should accept your answer or not, because my question was not clair enough :( I was looking for a way to get only the Event that triggered my function from Azure Monitor, I didn't want to get a list of Events with alerts.get all (which my and your code return). I will put below what I'm using to get only the Event that triggered my Azure Function.